# Need to auto-change the color of cells updated by vlookup formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two sheets named source.xls and dest.xls.

**Source.xls**

[image]

**Dest.xls**

[image]

Now I have applied the vlookup formula(=VLOOKUP(A3,[sourc.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$C$13,2,FALSE)) in dest excel so as I enter 1 it picks the name and marks (=VLOOKUP(A3,[sourc.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$C$13,3,FALSE) ) from source sheet. And it is perfectly working.

Now my question is I want auto change of the color of cells in dest sheet as it gets updated by source.xls as I need to list those changes. Currently if I am opening the dest.xls file it gets updated but I unable to find the updated cells from the last change.

I want as I open the dest sheet beat multiple times I  would be able to see the changed cells so that I can list that up.

Comment: Actually I dont have idea that VBA is the technology which can achieve so I have updated my question now. So waiting how we can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I just have a question : How many S.No do you have on source.xls ??

Now  you have to  choose which is the cell you want to change the color for example every time that you enter the So No do you want to change the color to the name cell or mark cell

For example lets do it for the first 1000 cells under column B with the Name Title

1-Highlight from cell B2 to B1000
2-Select Conditional formatting option and then New Rule 
3-finally select the option that say Use a formula to determine which cell to format
4- Where is saying Format values where this formula is true enter the following formula

=$A2>0

5- Press click on format and select the fill color and then hit OK

Now every time that you enter a number on any cell under column B the vlookup will give you the name and mark but the name will be highlithed

In case one day you complete 300 So No. you can edit the conditional formatting formula to be =$A2>300

This will work if you enter a different value on each row but if you enter a duplicate so No. you will need a  macro or add an extra column which I think is better

Comment: Requirement is: As source file changed, dest file must be updated as well with highlighted cells which got updated. lets say 3rd and 7th cells updated in source file and as I open dest vlookup runs and update the value but make it highlight also so that i can List that 3rd and 7th cell value is updated now. And this can be done multiple times in a day.